# Google Map Overlay for Android Apps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map image , which I want show as an overlay on Google map in my android app.But the image is 9 mb in size. I put it as an overlay , when the user try to zoom the map , app crashes due to memory issue.

Does anybody know how we can show an image as overlay using less memory in android apps?

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to scale the image before displaying it as described [here](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.be/2012/08/thanks-for-memories.html)